# How to deal with error dimension in multiple linear regression?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, data-science, linear-regression

I am trying to make multiple linear regression with sklearn.

```
features_2 = ['chronic_disease_binary', 'outcome']

X = df.loc[:, features_2].values
Y = df.loc[:, ['age']].values
# X = pd.get_dummies(X,drop_first=True)
#
X_train_lm, X_test_lm, y_train_lm, y_test_lm = create_dataset_test(X, Y)
X_train_lm = X_train_lm.reshape((2596, -1))
lm = linear_model.LinearRegression()
model = lm.fit(X_train_lm, y_train_lm)
y_pred_lm = lm.predict(X_test_lm)
```

I have this issue when I am trying tp make prediction on X_test :

> ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 2 is different from 1)

- My X_train has this form :

```
[[-0.77046461  1.29791815]
 [-0.77046461 -0.77046461]
 [-0.77046461  1.29791815]
 ...
 [-0.77046461 -0.77046461]
 [-0.77046461  1.29791815]
 [-0.77046461 -0.77046461]]
```

- And my y_train is like this :

```
[[59.]
 [54.]
 [40.]
 ...
 [24.]
 [33.]
 [41.]]
```

- The data where I make my prediction has this form :

```
[[-0.76666002]
 [ 1.30435914]
 [-0.76666002]
 ...
 [-0.76666002]
 [-0.76666002]
 [-0.76666002]]
```

Comment: What does `X_test_lm.shape` give you?

Comment: @AmiTavory it gives me (1300, 1)

Comment: see my answer! As I said you have mismatch in the dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

**Dimension mismatch.**

You have incompatible dimensions, since `X_test_lm` has N (number of rows) samples **but only 1 (number of columns) feature/variable compared to the shape of `X_train`.**

---

Details:

You have a `X_train` as:

```
[[-0.77046461  1.29791815]
 [-0.77046461 -0.77046461]
 [-0.77046461  1.29791815]
 ...
 [-0.77046461 -0.77046461]
 [-0.77046461  1.29791815]
 [-0.77046461 -0.77046461]]
```

**so the model is trained on N (number of rows) samples with 2 (number of columns) features/variables.**

Then, when you ask to predict the:

```
[[-0.76666002]
 [ 1.30435914]
 [-0.76666002]
 ...
 [-0.76666002]
 [-0.76666002]
 [-0.76666002]]
```

you have incompatible dimesnions, since `X_test_lm` has again N (number of rows) samples **but this time only 1 (number of columns) feature/variable.**

But, the `predict` function of the model expects an input an array with shape [N,2] and you get:

> ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core
>   dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 2 is
>   different from 1)

As you said, `X_test_lm.shape` is (1300, 1) so the model is trying to predict the values of these 1300 samples having only one feature (1). That's what triggers the error. The model was training using the `X_train` that had shape [N,2] **not** [N,1].

---

Answer (score 1):

As the value of `X_test_lm.shape` is `(1300, 1)`, it means that it has only 1 column, not 2 as the train data. The beta vector trained on the trained data expects a matrix with 2 columns, which gives the error.

You should check the definition of `create_dataset_test` to see how you got to this state.